# QT QML QtLocation map plugin

Tags: qt, qml, qtlocation

I have my own local Z/X/Y map tile server and want to use it as a map background in a QML application. Looking at sample code it appears that this is done by:-

```
 Plugin {
    id: osmPlugin
    name: "osm"
 }
```

So I need to write my own plugin. But the documentation seems sparse and I cannot find the source code for the osm version or installation instructions.

Is this relatively easy to do, or can it be done without writing a new plugin?

Answer (score 6):

You can set the osm.mapping.host like this:

```
    Plugin {
        id: osmPlugin
        name: "osm"


        PluginParameter { name: "osm.mapping.host"; value: "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/" }
        PluginParameter { name: "osm.geocoding.host"; value: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org" }
        PluginParameter { name: "osm.routing.host"; value: "https://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute" }
        PluginParameter { name: "osm.places.host"; value: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search" }
        PluginParameter { name: "osm.mapping.copyright"; value: "" }
        PluginParameter { name: "osm.mapping.highdpi_tiles"; value: true }
    }
```

But don't forget to set Custom Map type using the following code:

```
    Map {
        id: map
        height: parent.width
        width: parent.width
        plugin: osmPlugin

        Component.onCompleted: {
            for( var i_type in supportedMapTypes ) {
                if( supportedMapTypes[i_type].name.localeCompare( "Custom URL Map" ) === 0 ) {
                    activeMapType = supportedMapTypes[i_type]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the documentation doesn't cover something or not in enough detail, it is always good to remember that [Qt's source](http://code.qt.io) is publically available.

For example the OSM plugin is [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtlocation.git/tree/src/plugins/geoservices/osm?h=dev)

The [Woboq code browser](https://code.woboq.org) is also really nice for that if you know the name of the class or file you are [looking for](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtlocation/src/plugins/geoservices/osm/qgeoserviceproviderpluginosm.h.html)

Comment: Thanks, but as for the second part of my question is there an alternative as it seems a lot of work especially given no comments in the OSM code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have figured out a way to do this without writing a plugin.

The OSM plugin uses a tileserver to retrieve tiles. The url is set with the plugin option *osm.mapping.custom.host* setting this to a local url allows me to use my own tiles as long as they conform to the osm structure.